# Custom View in Status Bar is Not Appearing Disabled on Secondary Screen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have an app that uses a custom view in the menu bar of macOS. macOS has a feature that items in the menu bar will appear disabled on a secondary screen (I think an alpha value will be added to the view).

When I remove the custom view from the Button, everything works fine. But when I use my custom view, the view always looks the same, no matter if it is the primary or the secondary monitor.

Even setting the property "appearsDisabled" does not change the look of the view.

This is the code that I am using:

```
private let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
private var view: HostView?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    self.createMainView()
    self.createMenuBarView()
}

fileprivate func createMenuBarView()
{
    // Remove all sub views from the view and create new ones.
    self.view?.subviews.removeAll()

    var width: CGFloat = 0
    for device in self.controller.model.devices
    {
        if let newView = self.createView(for: device.value, x: width)
        {
            self.view?.addSubview(newView.view)

            width += newView.width
        }
    }

    self.view?.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: MenuBar.height)

    self.statusItem.image = nil
    self.statusItem.length = width

    if let view = self.view
    {
        // Do I have to set some properties here?
        self.statusItem.button?.addSubview(view)
    }
}

fileprivate func createMainView()
{
    let view = HostView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32.0, height: MenuBar.height))
    view.menu = self.menu

    self.view = view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I am adding a NSView to the button of the NSStatusItem as a subview.

```
self.statusBarItem.button?.addSubview(myView)
```

When I set my custom view to the view-Property of the NSStatusItem, the view is grayed out on a secondary screen (note that this is deprecated since macOS 10.14).

Comment: It does not work for me with a custom view with different subviews like NSProgressIndicator (circular) and NSButton with image. Even NSTextfield does not appears grayed out on inactive display. How did you achieve this? Am i missing something here?
BTW it does work for NSImageView or using button with text instead of NSTextfield.